# How to retrieve MySQL EAV results like a relational table

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I need to extract results from one table organized as EAV-feed repository. **What I need is return results like a relational table.** I'm using an schema like that:

**Table Schema**

```
 meta table
-----------------------
idmeta  |  entity_identity(fk)  |  products_idproduct(fk)  |  products_feeds_idfeed(fk)  |  value                   |  
1       |                   1   |                       1  |                         1   |  First product first val |
2       |                   2   |                       1  |                         1   |  First product second val|
3       |                   1   |                       2  |                         1   |  2nd product first val   |
4       |                   2   |                       2  |                         1   |  2nd product second val  |
5       |                   1   |                       3  |                         1   |  3rd product first val   |
6       |                   2   |                       3  |                         1   |  3rd product second val  |
```

So I'm trying to extract all values from all products for each idfeed. In this case I'm trying to get somethig like this:

**Wanted results..**

```
+----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| products_idproduct | field1                   | field2                       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|                  1 | First product first val  | First product second val     |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|                  2 | 2nd product first val    | 2nd product second val       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|                  3 | 3rd product first val    | 3rd product second val       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I've been trying with some coalescing sentences but all I'm getting **only one row** because the MAX function, or some NULL values instead..:

**What I'm trying now..**

```
SELECT DISTINCT products_idproduct 
     , MAX( IF(entity_identity = 1, value, NULL) ) as 'field1'
     , MAX( IF(entity_identity = 2, value, NULL) ) as 'field2'
FROM meta
WHERE products_feeds_idfeed = 1;
```

And obsiously this only returns the last line (last product)..

```
+----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| products_idproduct | field1                   | field2                       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|                  3 | 3rd product first val    | 3rd product second val       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Any ideas about how can I get all product results like a relational table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people advise me some joins needed here... This is the sentence I'm using now (need to get some performance stats:

```
SELECT PROD1.products_idproduct 
     , PROD1.value as 'field1'
     , PROD2.value as 'field2'
     , PROD3.value as 'field3'
     , PROD4.value as 'field4'
FROM meta PROD1 LEFT JOIN meta PROD2 
  ON (    PROD1.products_feeds_idfeed = PROD2.products_feeds_idfeed
      AND PROD1.products_idproduct = PROD2.products_idproduct)
     LEFT JOIN meta PROD3
  ON (    PROD1.products_feeds_idfeed = PROD3.products_feeds_idfeed
      AND PROD1.products_idproduct = PROD3.products_idproduct)
     LEFT JOIN meta PROD4
  ON (    PROD1.products_feeds_idfeed = PROD4.products_feeds_idfeed
      AND PROD1.products_idproduct = PROD4.products_idproduct)
WHERE
      PROD1.products_feeds_idfeed = 1
  AND PROD1.entity_identity = 1
  AND PROD2.entity_identity = 2
  AND PROD3.entity_identity = 3
  AND PROD3.entity_identity = 4;
```